# creating conditional variable in R

Tags: r, variables, conditional-statements

For the following data set

```
> data
   x1 x2 x3
1   1  0  0
2   0  1  0
3   0  0  1
4   0  0  1
5   1  0  0
6   0  1  0
7   1  0  0
8   0  1  0
9   0  0  1
10  1  0  0
```

I would like to create new variable `z` such that it takes `1` if `x1=1`, `2` if `x2=1` and `3` if `x3=1`, `z` will look like `z=c(1,2,3,3,1,2,1,2,3,1)`. 
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there will be only one 1 in a given row as shown in the data shared, we can use `max.col`

```
data$z <- max.col(data)
data
#   x1 x2 x3 z
#1   1  0  0 1
#2   0  1  0 2
#3   0  0  1 3
#4   0  0  1 3
#5   1  0  0 1
#6   0  1  0 2
#7   1  0  0 1
#8   0  1  0 2
#9   0  0  1 3
#10  1  0  0 1
```

In case of multiple 1's in a given row explore the `ties.method` in `?max.col` which gives an option to get "first" or "last" 1.

If we want to return 0 if all the row values are 0 we can do :

```
data$z <- max.col(data) * +(rowSums(data == 1) > 0)
```

Comment: If the values of a row are zeros, I am getting `1` with `max.col(data)`. But the output should be `0` @Ronak